# Group By with aggregate For Getting Record In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need Group the `SP` column and  filter the Based On `Min` And `Max` Value of  `T`  and Get result In Select Query.

TABLE An

```
RawS    RawI  SS    SP  T
14299    52  14299  105 1
14299    53  14299  105 2
14299    54  14299  105 3
14299    56  14299  106 2
14299    57  14299  106 3
14299    58  14299  107 1
14299    59  14299  107 2
14299    60  14299  107 3
```

I tried With Small Query If I add column `Raws` in my Query then I am Getting SQL Error for aggregate Functions Use.

```
SELECT 
     ar1.SP,
     MIN(ar1.T) AS T1,
     MAX(ar1.T) AS T2 FROM An ar1
     Group by  ar1.SP
```

Require Output Format .

```
RawS1  RaWI1 RawS2  RawI2 SP     T1  T2
14299   52   14299  54    105    1   3
14299   56   14299  57    106    2   3
14299   58   14299  60    107    1   3
```

Comment: Well, you must have tried *something* then.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image. You have enough reputation to know how to copy and paste code/data and format it. Please do so.

Comment: Please no images, and post what you tried?

Comment: Please Check Now. @Larnu

Comment: Please Check Now @Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option for you.  Sub-query to get the min and max T for each SP.   Then 2 joins to get the other data.

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [RawS] INT
      , [RawI] INT
      , [SS] INT
      , [SP] INT
      , [T] INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [RawS]
                        , [RawI]
                        , [SS]
                        , [SP]
                        , [T]
                      )
VALUES ( 14299, 52, 14299, 105, 1 )
     , ( 14299, 53, 14299, 105, 2 )
     , ( 14299, 54, 14299, 105, 3 )
     , ( 14299, 56, 14299, 106, 2 )
     , ( 14299, 57, 14299, 106, 3 )
     , ( 14299, 58, 14299, 107, 1 )
     , ( 14299, 59, 14299, 107, 2 )
     , ( 14299, 60, 14299, 107, 3 );


SELECT     [a1].[RawS] AS [RawS1]
         , [a1].[RawI] AS [RawI1]
         , [a2].[RawS] AS [RawS1]
         , [a2].[RawI] AS [RawI2]
         , [a].*
FROM       (
               SELECT   [SP]
                      , MIN([T]) AS [T1]
                      , MAX([T]) AS [T2]
               FROM     @TestData
               GROUP BY [SP]
           ) AS [a]
INNER JOIN @TestData [a1]
    ON [a1].[SP] = [a].[SP]
       AND [a1].[T] = [a].[T1]
INNER JOIN @TestData [a2]
    ON [a2].[SP] = [a].[SP]
       AND [a2].[T] = [a].[T2];
```

Comment: It's possible without inner query ? @Tim Mylott

Comment: @PrashantGupta I don't know.  That's how I understood your requirement and without a larger sample set of data it's a challenge to know if using aggregate functions on the other columns is really going to give you what you're after.

Comment: @PrashantGupta I'm sure this is a smaller sample set of data with what you are working with.   Are RawS values always the same?  Would the order of RawI values based on SP always follow a similar sequence to the T value?  We might need a broader context and understanding of your data.

Answer (score 0):

This *appears* to get you the result you're after:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (14299,52,14299,105,1),
                 (14299,53,14299,105,2),
                 (14299,54,14299,105,3),
                 (14299,56,14299,106,2),
                 (14299,57,14299,106,3),
                 (14299,58,14299,107,1),
                 (14299,59,14299,107,2),
                 (14299,60,14299,107,3))V(RawS,RawI,SS,SP,T))
SELECT RawS,
       Min(RawI) AS RawI1,
       SS AS RawS2,
       MAX(RawI) AS RawI2,
       SP,
       MIN(T) AS T1,
       MAX(T) AS T2
FROM VTE
GROUP BY RawS,
         SS,
         SP;
```

No idea why you were getting an error, as that query ran fine [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=980a73d5c4b74be67fde0e591c9e2e97), which means that wasn't the query you were running.

Comment: Why with is required .  I am not able to understand this query. Can you please explain ? @Larnu

Comment: @PrashantGupta I needed some sample data I could use! Text, on it's own, isn't consumable, so I used a CTE (or "VTE" (Values Table Expresssion)) to actually write a query I could test.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just MIN and MAX functions, grouping on SP and SS (which isn't in your required output)?

```
with An as (
      select 14299 as RawS ,52 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,105 as SP ,1 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,53 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,105 as SP ,2 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,54 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,105 as SP ,3 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,56 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,106 as SP ,2 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,57 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,106 as SP ,3 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,58 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,107 as SP ,1 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,59 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,107 as SP ,2 as T
union select 14299 as RawS ,60 as RawI ,14299 as SS ,107 as SP ,3 as T
)
select min(RawS) as RawS1
     , min(RawI) as RawI1
     , max(RawS) as RawS2
     , max(RawI) as RawI2
     , SP
     , min(T) as T1
     , max(T) as T2
  from An
group by SP, SS
```